# Angular: This type is not supported as injection token

Tags: angular, typescript

I am just trying to create a constructor with type number but I am getting the error as 'This type is not supported as injection token'

I am new to Angular. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector : 'app-even',
    templateUrl : './even.component.html',
    styleUrls : ['./even.component.css']
})
export class EvenComponent
{
    num : number;
    
    constructor(num : number){
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error:

[image: Injection type error]

I use this EvenComponent in AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck{
  evenCounts : EvenComponent[];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass data to a component, you need to use `@Input()`. For example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector : 'app-even',
    templateUrl : './even.component.html',
    styleUrls : ['./even.component.css']
})
export class EvenComponent implements OnInit
{
    @Input() num : number;
    
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        // You can use this value now
        console.log(this.num);

    }

}
```

To pass the value into the component, you add the following to the parent HTML template:

```
<app-even [num]="3"></app-even>
```

Note: You can't use the values passed into a component in the constructor because the value won't be ready yet and you'll always get `undefined`.

If you're new to Angular it might be worth going through the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial to pick up some core knowledge.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Angular is trying to resolve the dependency of num. If you are trying to pass num to component, I suggest using @Input() decorator

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection